# splash screen shown on device, but not after Ad Hoc Distribution

Tags: ios, splash-screen, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

Please help.
I added a splash screen to my project.
First the launch image is shown, than my localized splash screen is shown for 2 seconds, fading to my first screen.

When installalling directly form Xcode on my device, everything works okay.
When I build an ipa archive and distribute via TestFlight, after install on the same device, the splash screen isn't shown: immediately after launch image my first screen appears.

My device is a iPhone 4S, with iOS 6.0.1.
Deployment target is set to 5.0 and I use Xcode 4.5.2.

Code for splash screen at the bottom of my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
// Splash screen
UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"Splash_NL.PNG", @"Bestandsnaam splash screen")]];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.frame = self.window.bounds;
[[navigationController view] addSubview:imageView];
[[navigationController view] bringSubviewToFront:imageView];

// as usual
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// korte pauze, dan fade out
[self performSelector:@selector(_fadeSplash:) withObject:imageView afterDelay:1.0];
```

and after that

```
- (void) _fadeSplash:(UIView *)view
{
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:2.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^(void){view.alpha=0.0f;} completion:^(BOOL finished){[view removeFromSuperview];}];
}
```

Any help is appreciated; I'm lost/desperate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved. Some time before build of the archive, I supplied new splash screen images. The extension of these files was .png instead of .PNG.

I reckoned the splash screen on the device (via Xcode) should have failed as well (I deleted the previous version of the app before running/building), but obviously somehow these resource files were kept in memory or something.
Changing extension and rebuilding the archive solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the image in question on the left pane that shows your project folders and files.  In the file inspector under the target membership box, make sure it is added to all targets that you are building with and that you need it in.  I am thinking that you might have several targets and the image is not added to all of them.

Comment: Alas; I only have one target and it is selected for both localized files.